# If all strings either need a length or null terminator, how do high level languages just construct a string with chars?

Tags: python, c, go

So I am writing some C code to play around with mocking up a scripting language.
I ran into a scenario where if I run a function to import a file, say `import("file.c")` I run into an issue where I can not necessarily use a pointer because it is not null terminated. I would also need to give the length of the string like `import("file.c", 5)` or use a null terminating character `import("file.c\0")`. I assume using a buffer is the way to go with a fixed size such as `char file_name[256]` which probably covers a file name large enough. But that raises some interesting questions regarding 'higher' level programming languages like say Python or Golang. So Golong's imports look like this from a internet search:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)
```

I would assume the libraries are being treated as string, no? What about Python?

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import functools
```

Are those also being treated as strings? At least, to me, I would assume golang's imports are.
But let's forget imports entirely. What about just strings?
Python's string is:

```
s = "I like Apple Pie"
```

I saw [here](https://go101.org/article/string.html) that strings in golang are defined as:

```
type _string struct {
    elements *byte // underlying bytes
    len      int   // number of bytes
}
```

Then the next segment of code says:

```
const World = "world"
```

where there is no len specified. What gives?

How does golang, or in general, 'higher' level languages make use of strings without having to specify a null terminated string or the length with a number? Or am I missing something entirely?

I come from a Python background with some C but it seems pretty similar in most programming languages today.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your title correctly says "strings need either a length or a [...] terminator". The Golang example struct/type has a length, and the source code ``"world"`` clearly has a beginning *and terminating* symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you don't write string length or the null terminating character for a string literal does not mean that it cannot be done automatically: the compiler can do it (because it knows the string length at compilation time) and is very likely doing it.

For example in [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

> The null character ('\0', L'\0', char16_t(), etc) is always
>   appended to the string literal: thus, a string literal "Hello" is a
>   const char[6] holding the characters 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', and
>   '\0'.

Here is a small C program that show that null character is appended to string literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char *p="hello";
   int i;

   i = 0;   
   while (p[i] != '\0')
   {
        printf("%c ", p[i]);
        i++;
   }
   printf("\nstrlen(p)=%ld\n", strlen(p));

   return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./hello
h e l l o 
strlen(p)=5
```

You can also compile the program in debug mode with:

```
gcc -g -o hello -Wall -pedantic -Wextra hello.c
```

and check with `gdb`:

```
    gdb hello
    ...

    (gdb) b main
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x400585: file hello.c, line 6.
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: /home/pifor/c/hello 
    Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.c:6  
    6      char *p="hello";
    (gdb) n
    9      i = 0;   
    (gdb) print *(p+5)
    $7 = 0 '\000'
    (gdb) print *(p+4)
    $8 = 111 'o' 
    (gdb) print *p
    $10 = 104 'h'
```

Comment: Okay, gotcha so a nul terminator is appended behind the scenes.

Comment: I would suppose most languages do this behind the scenes where they either get the length or append a null terminator without the user knowing.

Comment: do you have an example of C code that shows how to automatically append the null terminator. Looks like the link shows c++

Comment: I have added a C example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A string value in Go is a pointer to bytes and a length. Here's [Go's definition of the type](https://godoc.org/reflect#StringHeader):

```
type StringHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
}
```

In the case of a string literal like `"world"`, the compiler counts the bytes to set the length.  The literal is represented by  `StringHeader{Data: pointerToBytesWorld, Len: 5}` at runtime.

The length is implicit in the slice operands for a string value through a slice expression:

```
 s := "Hello"
 s = s[1:4]   // length is 4 - 1 = 3
```

String conversions take the length from the operand:

```
 b := []byte{'F', 'o', 'p'}
 s = string(b)  // length is 3, same as len(b)
```

Comment: Okay gotcha, so golang is sending the length behind the scenes. Interesting, thanks!